# MariaDB start up issue in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mariadb, panel, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to install pterodactyl using the following script but mariadb was constantly having problem during loading

```
https://github.com/vilhelmprytz/pterodactyl-installer
```

while `running journalctl -xe` I get the following output

````
root@ryno-pterodactyl:~# journalctl -xe
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
-- The job identifier is 1400. 
Apr 06 11:54:54 ryno-pterodactyl PackageKit[22129]: daemon quit Apr 06 11:54:54 pterodactyl systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded. 
-- Subject: Unit succeeded 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- The unit packagekit.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state. Apr 06 12:01:01 ryno-pterodactyl CRON[22315]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) Apr 06 12:01:01 ryno-pterodactyl CRON[22316]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) Apr 06 12:01:01 ryno-pterodactyl CRON[22315]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root Apr 06 12:04:50 ryno-pterodactyl systemd[1]: mariadb.service: start operation timed out. Terminating. Apr 06 12:04:52 ryno-pterodactyl systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'. 
-- Subject: Unit failed 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'. Apr 06 12:04:52 ryno-pterodactyl systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server. 
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
-- The job identifier is 1400 and the job result is failed. Apr 06 12:04:52 ryno-pterodactyl systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 1.363s CPU time. 
-- Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- The unit mariadb.service completed and consumed the indicated resources. lines 3832-3866/3866 (END)```
````

Comment: I hope you started [here](https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/getting_started.html#dependencies). did you check the `dependencies`, and the following paragraph [Installation](https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/getting_started.html#installation) ?    ( I do mean did you change your password, and did that work OK ?)

Comment: i simply ran a script with which i used to deploy panel in aws and hetzner but when i tried to deploy in my home server this error is showing up
https://prnt.sc/u9YRrNmp4hAW

Comment: Ok, you ran `"a script" and now you hope that someone who does not know where "a script" came from can help you ?

Comment: @Luuk i have linked the script above but basically i believe "maybe" its a something clashing between mysql and mariadb

Comment: Ask author of that script (on github)   On the link you gave (https://github.com/vilhelmprytz/pterodactyl-installer) there is not mentioning on a database (MySQL or MariaDB) being installed...

Comment: oh nvm i got the fix there was some issue with the container
It worked well when i got a fresh vm install 
Thanks